# working with asp.net login control

Tags: asp.net, login-control

hey guys,
i am using asp.net login control, here i am using onauthenticate event to check whether the user has been authenticated so that i can redirect them to the appropriate page, the funny thing happening over here, is when i dont implement onauthenticated event, everything goes well, but when i implement the onauthenticated event, asp.net does not allows to log me in and throws a invalid credential, when i remove the onauthenticated event it works well, so how can i check which user logged in, i think this is the only event which i can use for this purpose...

Please reply how should i check which user logged in...
Thanks and reply
Abbas Electricwala.

Comment: Provide some code. The Login-Control with the OnAuthenticated-Event works just fine. You probably did something wrong

Comment: protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) { if (e.Authenticated) Response.Write(true); else Response.Write(false); } this is the code i am using to check whether the user is validated and display simple response message, but it always goes in else and throws invalid credentials message, but after removing this event, it works properly.. any LUCK..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a LoggedIn event that you can check, or maybe LoggingIn.

HTH.

Comment: protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Authenticated) Response.Write(true);
        else Response.Write(false);
    }
this is the code i am using to check whether the user is validated and display simple response message, but it always goes in else and throws invalid credentials message, but after removing this event, it works properly..

any LUCK...